# Invalid Assignment Operator Error >= Java

Tags: java, assignment-operator

I have an if statement that is throwing "invalid assignment operator" in Java (on both lines). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated:

```
if ((row >= 0) && (row < this.rows) && ((col – 1) >= 0) && ((col – 1) < this.cols)) {
         nbrNeighbors += grid[row][col – 1]; 
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the types of these variables, it's hard to suggest a definitive solution.

Comment: All variables are int type:

public int getNbrNeighbors(int row, int col) {
  int nbrNeighbors = 0;

  if ((row >= 0) && (row < this.rows) && ((col – 1) >= 0) && ((col – 1) < this.cols)) {
       nbrNeighbors += grid[row][col – 1];        // the above “if” checks whether the element you are accessing in the grid is within bounds
  }

  return nbrNeighbors;
 }

Comment: Don't add details in comments: [edit].

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a wrong character for the minus operation: – ('EN DASH' (U+2013)). Try to use - instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your example in my IDE and the only thing that seems wrong for me is your minus(-) character: 
`Illegal character (U+2013)`.

Try to paste my version:

`if ((row >= 0) && (row < this.rows) && ((col - 1) >= 0) && ((col - 1) < this.cols)) {
    nbrNeighbors += grid[row][col - 1];
}`